# iframe with lightbox

Tags: html, iframe, lightbox

(sorry for my english..)

I've got an iFrame that load some page when i click some button.
These pages contain some that open a zoom in a lightbox.
My problem: lightbox is inside the iFrame, and i need that it is in 100%.

the code here:

```
<a title="" href="ips-emax-tech-cad_1.jpg?v=1" rel="lightbox[pics]"><img src="ips-emax-tech-cad_1.jpg?v=1" alt="" title="" /></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
LightboxOptions = Object.extend({fileLoadingImage: 'lightbox/images/loading.gif', fileBottomNavCloseImage: '
lightbox/images/closelabel.gif', overlayOpacity: 0.8, animate: true, resizeSpeed: 8, borderSize: 10, labelImage: 'Image', labelOf: 'of' }, window.LightboxOptions || {});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean you want the lightbox to take up the whole page not just the iframe within that page. It's not possible, the lightbox must exist in the main page.